# R language to extract numeric parts of strings

Tags: r, regex

I have  a list of strings in a variable `resHeaders` :

```
> resHeaders
[1] "Rodrigu12ez/Schoofs 1 0 15 123  Jakupo15vic/Khromacheva 0 0 15 15 "
[2] "Mariano Kestelboim 0 6  Gonzalo Lama 0 6 "         
[3] "Alexander Ward 0 4 40 Luke Bambridge 0 2 30"          
[4] "Lucas Pouille 0 0 0 Steve Darcis 0 0 0"
```

I want to extract the numbers in the middle and at the end .
The result should be like that :

```
> resHeaders
[1]  1 0 15 123 0 0 15 15 
[2]  0 6 0 6 
[3]  0 4 40 0 2 30     
[4]  0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Try `library(stringr);lapply(str_extract_all(resHeaders, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=\\s)"), as.numeric)`

Comment: it gives a wrong result

Comment: For me, it is giving the expected output `lapply(str_extract_all(resHeaders, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=(\\s|\\b))"), as.numeric)#[[1]]
[1]   1   0  15 123   0   0  15  15

[[2]]
[1] 0 6 0 6

[[3]]
[1]  0  4 40  0  2 30

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: @akrun
 Somehow it miss the last number for  the last  two lines . And you can see that there is not a space ' ' at their end . So i just have to add it and the result is fine ! thank you so much

Comment: I copied from your example and it is working fine for me.  So, probably it is different in your case.  If you notice that I also used `\\b` in the above comment

Comment: I didn't notice that and yes the above comment with \\b fixed it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` to extract all the numbers.  As the numbers to be extracted follow a space before or after (or at the end of the string), we can use the regex lookarounds.  The output will be a `list` of `vector`s.  Loop through the `list` with `lapply` and convert the strings to `numeric` class

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(resHeaders, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=(\\s|\\b))"), as.numeric)
#[[1]]
#[1]   1   0  15 123   0   0  15  15

#[[2]]
#[1] 0 6 0 6

#[[3]]
#[1]  0  4 40  0  2 30

#[[4]]
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
resHeaders <- c("Rodrigu12ez/Schoofs 1 0 15 123  Jakupo15vic/Khromacheva 0 0 15 15 ", 
"Mariano Kestelboim 0 6  Gonzalo Lama 0 6 ", "Alexander Ward 0 4 40 Luke Bambridge 0 2 30", 
"Lucas Pouille 0 0 0 Steve Darcis 0 0 0")
```